# convert PHP's eregi to preg_match

Tags: php, wamp, eregi

I dont know how to fixe this error

```
 Warning: preg_match(): Unknown modifier '[' in
```

my code is

```
while(list($k,$v)=each($con2)) {
    $patt="($this->block_start_word|$this->block_end_word)[[:blank:]]*([0-9a-zA-Z\_]+)[[:blank:]]*$this->block_end_delim(.*)";
    if (eregi($patt,$v,$res)) {
```

I want to update php version of eregi to preg_match and I try this

```
hile(list($k,$v)=each($con2)) {
    $patt="($this->block_start_word|$this->block_end_word)[[:blank:]]*([0-9a-zA-Z\_]+)[[:blank:]]*$this->block_end_delim(.*)";
    if ( preg_match($patt,$v,$res)) {
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot the delimiters for the regex, so just change this:

```
if ( preg_match($patt,$v,$res)) {
```

to:

```
if ( preg_match("/" . $patt . "/",$v,$res)) {
```

Comment: it display a blank page

Comment: @New_World You don't show any code which prints anything! Take a look into the linked answer, but otherwise there is nothing which prints something in your code!